# Will landing pages not linked from anywhere negatively affect SERP ranking?

Tags: seo, links, search-results, landing-page

I want to make a few key landing pages based on what people are searching for about our product. However, I really don't need or want to link to those pages from anywhere on our website. Stuff people search for and can be found scattered around message boards is often centered on one of two things:

1. What is that security device I see all over X?
2. How can I get around that security device?

Neither one does our website rank for at all. I could make a landing page basically silencing a lot of those questions but I really don't need to link to that content from internally. It would just be for people actively searching ways to get around the product.

Will introducing landing pages for this that are indexed and followed but have no internal links negatively affect our SERP positioning?

Comment: I have found that pages that are not linked on the site somewhere may not appear in the SERPs. I had a site with too many pages to link. I used the sitemap and the pages were all indexed and doing rather well. The in June 2015 or so Google decided that sites that do not link to all of their pages are  to be treated differently and the pages that were not link dropped from the index. I had to wait to see a pattern to know for sure. Right or wrong, when I figured out what was actually going on, I pulled the plug. I suggest a link somewhere.

Comment: @closetnoc please post as an answer not a comment

Comment: Are you creating these landing pages for SEO?  Do you want those landing pages to rank in Google?   It is common to create landing pages for ad campaigns that aren't linked on the site.    It isn't common to create a "landing page" for SEO.   Landing pages are usually fairly content free.  They typically have sales language and a prominent call to action like "sign up now".   For SEO it is better to create content pages and articles.

Comment: BTW- My response is largely anecdotal and does not raise to the level of an answer. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of landing page is known as a 'doorway page', they used to work great before Google came along with the page rank algorithm.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721311?hl=en
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doorway_page

Even if you aren't using your landing pages for spamdexing they will probably be seen as spam by the search engines, at best they will be ignored.

I suggest linking to your landing pages, at least from the html sitemap, or some other page that nobody ever visits :)